# css selector with not(rule AND rule ...)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to create a CSS selector that only matches the external links. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work with multiple rules in :not(). I can not use multiple not ( `example: ":not():not()") because that becomes || instead of &&` ).

**Internal link**

```
<a href="#!/something">...</a>
```

**Document link**

```
<a href="/doc/.../binary/...">...</a>
```

**External link**

```
<a href="...whatever...">...</a>
```

**CSS selector for external links that does not match the other type of links.**

```
a:not([href^="#!/"]):not([href="#"]):not([href^="/doc/"][href*="/binary/"]) {}
```

**Explained**

```
a-tags NOT startswith hashbang || not hash || not (startswith /doc/ && contains /binary/)
```

It seems that it is not possible to have multiple rules in not(). Can this be solved in another way?

The HTML comes from a CMS and is almost attributes-less. Only "href" and "title" is allowed. Would be nice with a solution where I don't have to loop through the HTML with js and add classes or rel.

Comment: if your external links start with `http` or `//`why not target them only with `[href^="http"]` and `[href^="//"]`?

Comment: Cannot be done with :not(). But if I were you, I'd add a specific CSS class for external links such as class="extern"

Comment: @KhalidT. `rel="external"` is better for that purpose.

Comment: The link can also start with https:// or customscheme:// or even just / because it can be a another application in the same domain. There is so many cases that i wanted to invert the selector.

Comment: Chaining multiple :not()s is most definitely an &&, not an ||.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you do it like this

```css
a[href*="//"]:not([href*="yoursite.com"]),
a[href^="#"],
a[href^="/doc/"],
a[href*="/binary/"]{    
  color: red;
}
a{
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#!/something">HASH</a>

<a href="/doc/.../binary/...">Binary</a>

<a href="http://yoursite.com">Yoursite</a>
```